# Disable CORS check for multiple URLs in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, okta

I'm my application I'm using OKTA.

My application sends request to OKTA to URL: http://localhost:8080/oauth2/authorization/okta (Call #1)

OKTA then calls its URL: https://dev-1234567.okta.com/oauth2/v1/authorize (Call #2)

I want to disable CORS check for both my application & for `dev-1234567.okta.com` as well.

With below configs I'm able to disable CORS check for my application urls but not any other.

I tried had coding `dev-1234567.okta.com` in `addAllowedOrigin` as well but same issue.

What am I missing?

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource()).and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/app/**")
                .hasAnyAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN").anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                //........
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        configuration.addAllowedHeader("*");
        configuration.addAllowedMethod("GET");
        configuration.addAllowedMethod("PUT");
        configuration.addAllowedMethod("POST");
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okta is not calling your application with CORS, but your app calls Okta with CORS. So usually you'd need to enable CORS/Redirect in both of your Okta tenants for your http://localhost:8080 under Security->API->Trusted Origin